# Muliply more than two lists in data table

Tags: r, dictionary, data.table

How to multiply e.g. three lists in data table? Two lists are easy:

```
DT <- data.table(a = list(2,2,c(3,3),c(2,2)), b = list(2,2,c(3,3),c(2,2)),  d = list(2,2,c(3,3),c(2,2)) ) 
DT[, e := Map("*", a , b)]
```

My expected result is

```
DT <- data.table(a = list(2,2,c(3,3),c(2,2)), b = list(2,2,c(3,3),c(2,2)),  d = list(2,2,c(3,3),c(2,2)), e = list(8,8,c(27,27), c(8,8)) )
```

Solution `(DT[, e := Map("*", a , b, c )])` is not working, I also tried to use Reduce in place of Map, but it did not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` is a binary operator. How about this:

```
DT[, e := Map('*',DT$a,DT$b)]
DT[, e := Map('*',DT$d,DT$e)]
```

or

```
DT[, e := Map('*',Map('*',DT$a,DT$b),DT$d)]
```

Comment: Even better. Thanks.